# Start App/Activity by clicking Notification in my App

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am a beginner in Android-Programming and I need your help.
I want to start the activity "Notification" when I am clicking on the Androidnotification. The things I found to this topic on Stackoverflow, did not work.
So I hope you can help me.

Bootreceiver:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_icon);
    builder.setContentTitle("Warnung");
    builder.setContentText("Stromzähler 1 braucht 90% zu viel Strom");

    Intent in = new Intent(context, Notification.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(in);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());

}
}
```

Class Notification:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notification);

    loadBackHome();
    loadAllNotifications();

}
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is my code.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                    .setContentTitle("Title....")
                    .setContentText("Bla bla bla~~~~")
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

}
```

Comment: lil bit outdated, now (API 26) you need to provide channelId and setup Notification channel: new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId). Also notificationManager.notify(0, notification); - here shouldn't be 0, it should be meaningful notificationId (unique)